# Moq how to test BusinessLayer

Tags: moq

I have problem with the Unit Test my Module from Business Layer.
I'm using Moq.

my Module from DL :

```
namespace EF.BusinessLayer.Modules
{
    public class UserModule : IUserModule
    {


        public User AddUser(User user)
        {
            using (IUnitOfWork uow = IoC.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>())
            {
                uow.Add(user);
                uow.SaveChanges();
                return uow.Queryable<User>().Where(x => x.Username == user.Username).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test, with which I can test if my entity was added properly.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AddUserTestMethod()
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = "Criss",
            LastName = "Johnson",
            Username = "CJ",
            Email = "email@cj.com"
        };

        var mockContext = new Mock<IUserModule>();
        mockContext.Setup<User>(x => x.AddUser(user)).Callback<User>((c) => User = c);
        var result = mockContext.Object.AddUser(user);
    }
```

but results = null.
What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets understand what is your system under test (SUT). From your description, I think it's `UserModule`.

Note that `UserModule` depends on `IUnitOfWork`, which you have very rightly dependency injected using an `IoC` container.

One of the key things of unit testing is to test the SUT in isolation. Which means for testing the business logic under `UserModule`, you should be mocking the `IUnitOfWork`. That's the problem I see with your test. It mocks the `UserModule` itself.

I suggest you to register the mocked IUnitOfWork in your IoC container before calling the "AddUser" method of UserModule.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddUserTestMethod()
{
    /*given*/
    User expectedUser = new User()
    {
        FirstName = "Criss",
        LastName = "Johnson",
        Username = "CJ",
        Email = "email@cj.com"
    };

    var users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(expectedUser);
    //mock IUnitWork
    var mockUnitOfWork= new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Add(user));
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges());
    //This may not work as is, could need modification
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Queryable<User>()).Returns(users);

    //Register mocked unit of work in IoC container
    IoC.Register<IUnitOfWork>(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

   //Instantiate SUT
   var userModule = new UserModule();

    /*when*/
    var result = userModule.AddUser(user);

   /*then*/
   //Assert here
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But I need to show you applications layers that I made. here you have small solution : www.sendspace.com/file/3tzcvb

looking forward for help